# Javascript Array Count and delete zero's

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, count

**I have an Array let test =** `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,4,5,6,3,0,0,0,0,4,6,7]`

**I need to count the amount of zero's from the starting point in this case "9" upto value 3**

**Next want to only delete the first nine entries . The remaining zero's in the rest of the array must remain.**

***Expected Result***

**Count  = 9**
**Let Test =** `[3,4,5,6,3,0,0,0,0,4,6,7]`

Comment: Could you please also add what did you try to achieve the result?

Comment: No code , have no idea how to do this

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the result of your example should be `Count = 10` because there are 10 of `0`.

I suppose you want to define a function to get the result. That can be:

```
const func = (arr) => {
    let count = 0
    for (let i in arr) {
        if (arr[i] != 0) {
            break
        }
        count++
    }
    return [count, arr.slice(count)]
}

// Test:
const array = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,4,5,6,3,0,0,0,0,4,6,7]
console.log(`Count = ${func(array)[0]}, Array = ${func(array)[1]}`)
// Result should be Count = 10, Array = [3,4,5,6,3,0,0,0,0,4,6,7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code :

```js
function firstZeros(r) {

    var c = 0,s=true,nr=[];
    for(let ri of r){
        if(s && ri==0){
            c++;
        }else{
            s=false;        
            nr.push(ri);
        }
    }
    
    return {'count':c,'data':nr};
}


let test = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,4,5,6,3,0,0,0,0,4,6,7];

let res = firstZeros(test);

console.log('Count='+res.count);
console.log('Test='+res.data);
```

Thanks